# how to return from a pushed page without reloading the parent page again in ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a main tab (home page) where all posts are shown and once clicked on the post it will push the post detail page:

On `home.ts`:

```
 show_detail_page(id,title,content){

    this.navCtrl.push(PostDetailPage, {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        content: content 
    });
 }
```

On `Postdetailpage.ts`

```
back() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    //this.navCtrl.pop(); also tried this method
}
```

The reason it will reload all my posts upon entering home page again is because I have the posts loaded in the `ionViewWillEnter()` function on `home.ts`:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){

  firebase.database().ref('/posts/').once('value').then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => { 

         //rest of the code
        });
  });
```

I would like to dismiss the detail page without reloading the home page, or push the detail page on stack in a way that it will act like a pop up page?

Answer (score 1):

Since `ionViewWillenter()` is triggered every time we navigate to home page.
(regardless if returning from detail page or navigating from other main page to home page)

I have changed loading data in `ionViewWillenter()` to `ionViewDidLoad()` as this will be triggered once when the page is pushed to the navigation stack.

So when I go back from the details page to the home page, the home page is not reloaded with new data + it stays on the same scroll position (which i think is cool and more user friendly)

```
ionViewDidLoad(){ //triggered only once when pushed to navigation stack

 firebase.database().ref('/posts/').once('value').then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => { 

     //rest of the code
    });
 });
```

But now how to reload the data?

using the `<ion-refresher>` approach, where users can manually pull down to reload/refresh the page:

on `home.html`

```
   <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event);">
     <ion-refresher-content 
       pullingText="Pull to refresh" 
       pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" 
       refreshingSpinner="circles"
       refreshingText="..fetching">
     </ion-refresher-content> 
   </ion-refresher>
```

on `home.ts`

```
 doRefresh(refresher) {

    firebase.database().ref('/posts/').once('value').then(snapshot => {

      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => { 

        //rest of the code
      });
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I tried different ways, nothing worked out. Finally i landed on a post in ionic forum where one of the guy explained about how he solved it using Observables in angular v5.

Please refer to his post in medium.
https://medium.com/wizpanda/dealing-with-breaking-change-in-ionic-5-db3ba711dfcd